# split text into words and exclude hyphens

Tags: regex

I want to split a text into it's single words using regular expressions. The obvious solution would be to use the regex `\\b` unfortunately this one does split words also on the hyphen.

So I am searching an expression doing exactly the same as the `\\b` but does not split on hyphens.

Thanks for your help.

Example:

```
String s = "This is my text! It uses some odd words like user-generated and need therefore a special regex.";

String [] b = s.split("\\b+");
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    System.out.println(b[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
This

is

my

text
! 
It

uses

some

odd

words

like

user
-
generated

and

need

therefore

a

special

regex
.
```

Expected output:

```
...
like

user-generated

and
....
```

@Matmarbon solution is already quite close, but not 100% fitting it gives me

```
...
like

user-
generated

and
....
```

Comment: Example input and expected matches please!

Comment: arghh! a quantifier with `\\b` has no sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, even if lookaheads are not available:

```
[^\w\-]+
```

Also not you but somebody who needs this for another purpose (i.e. inserting something) this is more of an equivalent to the `\b`-solutions:

```
([^\w\-]|$|^)+
```

because:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

--- http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Just changed it D: but its more accurately now in my opinion.

Comment: Why would you want to split before the first and after the last character, though? Wouldn't that return empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(?<!-)\\b(?!-)
```